# Arduino on ubuntu 14.4 gives "Broken pipe" and "Input/output error"

Tags: arduino-uno

Im using arduino (R2) uno board and my pc is running 64bit ubuntu 14.4.
I was previously using arduino on ubuntu 10.04 for a long time and got no error. I recently moved to 14.4 from 10.4.

I installed arduino using this command

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino arduino-core
```

later arduino appeared, but was not working. According to [this link](http://vishnuvarkala.blogspot.in/2012/07/arduino-ide-not-detecting-serial-port.html), i was able to launch the IDE on mouse click. I then tried to upload servo examples, i get following errors.

```
Binary sketch size: 1,056 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Input/output error
```

I get the same error for even an Led blinking program too.

**Update 1:** (after Edgar's comment)

on terminal i get

```
~$ /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Servo /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.o
avr-g++: error: /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp: No such file or directory
avr-g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

But on the IDE, after enabling verbos i get

```
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Servo /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Servo -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Servo/utility /usr/share/arduino/libraries/Servo/Servo.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Servo/Servo.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring_analog.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/avr-libc/malloc.c -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/malloc.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/avr-libc/realloc.c -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/realloc.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring_digital.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring_pulse.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring.c -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring_shift.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/WInterrupts.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Stream.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HID.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/HID.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Print.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/WMath.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/CDC.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/CDC.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/new.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/new.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/HardwareSerial.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp: In function ‘void store_char(unsigned char, ring_buffer*)’:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp:100:20: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   if (i != buffer->tail) {
                    ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp: In function ‘void __vector_18()’:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp:129:21: warning: unused variable ‘c’ [-Wunused-variable]
       unsigned char c = UDR0;
                     ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp: In member function ‘void HardwareSerial::begin(long unsigned int, byte)’:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp:370:11: warning: unused variable ‘current_config’ [-Wunused-variable]
   uint8_t current_config;
           ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp: In member function ‘virtual size_t HardwareSerial::write(uint8_t)’:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp:469:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   while (i == _tx_buffer->tail)
                           ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/main.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/main.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Tone.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/IPAddress.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/USBCore.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.cpp -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/WString.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring_analog.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/malloc.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/realloc.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring_digital.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring_pulse.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/wiring_shift.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/WInterrupts.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Stream.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/HID.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Print.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/WMath.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/CDC.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/new.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/HardwareSerial.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/main.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Tone.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/IPAddress.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/USBCore.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/WString.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.elf /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Servo/Servo.cpp.o /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/core.a -L/tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp -lm 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.elf /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.eep 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.elf /tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.hex 
Binary sketch size: 2,554 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude -C/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/build4933543797518254688.tmp/Sweep.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 15:55:32
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/username/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": No such file or directory
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

**Update 2:** (tried again, this time i get "broken pipe". Led 13 blinks like crazy and my servo sounds different, no movement but continues sound)

```
.
.
.
avrdude: avr_read(): skipping page 253: no interesting data
avrdude: avr_read(): skipping page 254: no interesting data
avrdude: avr_read(): skipping page 255: no interesting data
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 2554 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: Send: Q [51]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 

avrdude done.  Thank you.

/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Servo /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp -o /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp.o 
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Servo/Servo.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring_analog.c.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/malloc.c.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/realloc.c.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring_digital.c.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring_pulse.c.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring.c.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring_shift.c.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/WInterrupts.c.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Stream.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/HID.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Print.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/WMath.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/CDC.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/new.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/HardwareSerial.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/main.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Tone.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/IPAddress.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/USBCore.cpp.o
  Using previously compiled: /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/WString.cpp.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring_analog.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/malloc.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/realloc.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring_digital.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring_pulse.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/wiring_shift.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/WInterrupts.c.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Stream.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/HID.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Print.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/WMath.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/CDC.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/new.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/HardwareSerial.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/main.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Tone.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/IPAddress.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/USBCore.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/WString.cpp.o 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp.elf /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp.o /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Servo/Servo.cpp.o /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/core.a -L/tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp -lm 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp.elf /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp.eep 
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp.elf /tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp.hex 
Binary sketch size: 2,554 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude -C/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/build4258280580047414287.tmp/Sweep.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 15:55:32
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/username/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Input/output error
```

Comment: 1. Check File → Preferences → Show verbose output during upload, 2. try again, 3. copy and paste the avrdude command line in a terminal and hit Enter, 4. post here all the output.

Comment: You have a communication problem.  The recommendation to try compilation commands from the terminal is not helping you, but merely showing that the files in /tmp are emphemeral.  Look into things like a flaky USB cable (or possibly an OS USB stack incompatible with quirks of your motherboard) which may be causing your board to "jump" to a different virtual port.  Check `dmesg` right after the failure.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I uploaded example code form arduino IDE. And regarding `brltty` i removed it using `sudo apt-get remove brltty`. or is there any other steps involved with `brltty`

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I think your point is correct, about changing the cable worked. But that too worked only for certain uploads. During some upload i get the very same `Broken pipe` and `Input/output error`. Dose this issue has to do anything with improper installation. Because, when i get that error, my Icon never works on clicking unless i restart whole system, or i have to remove the cable and kill the `avrdude` process through `sudo top` command and then initiate IDE by `sudo arduino` from terminal. only then i get serial port active and displayed

Comment: Does the file `/dev/ttyACM0` appear when you plug the Arduino and disappear when you unplug it?

Comment: @EdgarBonet - yes it dose. But while uploading the code, if i get the `broken pipe` error, it never appears until i restart the system or the arduino with some `pkill` or `top` command

Comment: You should never be running arduino (or any other IDE) under sudo.  If you *think* you need to do so, it is either because you have not given your account membership in the group which owns serial devices, or you have left behind files by running it as root in the past, which now only root can cleanup/replace.

Comment: If your /dev/ttyACM0 has failed for some reason *while in use*, a reconnection would probably show as /dev/ttyACM1 and so on, incrementing number.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I tried `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0` and then `sudo gpasswd -a _username_ dialout` also tried `sudo usermod -a -G dialout _username_` as suggested from various tutorials. All i can start the IDE is only using the sudo command. Are those the right way to add account membership ?
and about the `ttyACM0` and `ttyACM1` i do get those some times and i understood that part, thanks.

Comment: Please try using the last IDE version released here: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software The version 1.6.1 has many improvements about serial devices detection and sketches upload.

Comment: What the right group is depends on your installation.  "All i can start the IDE is only using the sudo command" has **nothing** to do with port permissions (you would only have a problem trying to download or open the serial monitor), but only with a broken install, possibly as a result of having made a mess by improperly running it as root in the past.

Comment: @lcipriani - I downloaded v1.6.1. It worked fine without any error. But after downloading im only able to open it from the directory where it resides. can you please help on how to open it from anywhere..?

Comment: @arvindh it would be nice if you can upvote my comment if it really helped you.

Comment: @lcipriani - i Know, I tried, and im sorry that i dont have enough `reputation points` to upvote your comment. Please write up the solution as an answer, i will remove my answer and mark yours as accepted,.. Im glad to do that instead of taking credit of others effort. Please feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the last IDE version released here: arduino.cc/en/Main/Software The version 1.6.1 has many improvements about serial devices detection and sketches upload. It will solve your issues about older Arduino UNO version and Arduino Yun.